# Establishing DB Connection (MongoDB, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to establish a connection to my `mongodb` database. I am working on two apps: one is allows you to create new customers and the other to read order statuses from the database.

However, I am only able to (locally) connect to one of the databases. If I try to connect via my second app, I always get connected to the previous database.

It would be much appreciated if someone could have a quick look and tell me where I am getting the connection wrong?

```
Db connection 1

const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
// name of our database
const dbname = "crud_mongodb";
// location of where our mongoDB database is located
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
// Options for mongoDB
const mongoOptions = {useNewUrlParser : true};

const state = {
    db : null
};

const connect = (cb) =>{

    if(state.db)
        cb();
    else{
        // attempt to get database connection
        MongoClient.connect(url,mongoOptions,(err,client)=>{
            // unable to get database connection pass error to CB
            if(err)
                cb(err);

            else{
                state.db = client.db(dbname);
                cb();
            }
        });
    }
}

// returns OBJECTID object used to 
const getPrimaryKey = (_id)=>{
    return ObjectID(_id);
}

// returns database connection 
const getDB = ()=>{
    return state.db;
}

module.exports = {getDB,connect,getPrimaryKey};

App:
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
// name of our database
const dbname = "crud_mongodb";
// location of where our mongoDB database is located
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
// Options for mongoDB
const mongoOptions = {useNewUrlParser : true};

const state = {
    db : null
};

const connect = (cb) =>{

    if(state.db)
        cb();
    else{
        // attempt to get database connection
        MongoClient.connect(url,mongoOptions,(err,client)=>{
            // unable to get database connection pass error to CB
            if(err)
                cb(err);

            else{
                state.db = client.db(dbname);
                cb();
            }
        });
    }
}

// returns OBJECTID object used to 
const getPrimaryKey = (_id)=>{
    return ObjectID(_id);
}

// returns database connection 
const getDB = ()=>{
    return state.db;
}

module.exports = {getDB,connect,getPrimaryKey};

db2:

const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
// name of our database
const dbname = "crud_mongodb";
// location of where our mongoDB database is located
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
// Options for mongoDB
const mongoOptions = {useNewUrlParser : true};

const state = {
    db : null
};

const connect = (cb) =>{

    if(state.db)
        cb();
    else{
        // attempt to get database connection
        MongoClient.connect(url,mongoOptions,(err,client)=>{
            // unable to get database connection pass error to CB
            if(err)
                cb(err);

            else{
                state.db = client.db(dbname);
                cb();
            }
        });
    }
}

// returns OBJECTID object used to 
const getPrimaryKey = (_id)=>{
    return ObjectID(_id);
}

// returns database connection 
const getDB = ()=>{
    return state.db;
}

module.exports = {getDB,connect,getPrimaryKey};

App2

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require('path');


const db = require("./db2");
const collection = "Order";
const app2 = express();

// Read and Update Orders

// read
app2.get('/Order',(req,res)=>{
    // get all orders within our order collection
    // send back to user as json
    db.getDB().collection(collection).find({}).toArray((err,result)=>{
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        else{
            console.log(result)
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean connecting to the previous db? you're connecting to the same database both times are you not?

Comment: yes exactly and i would want to connect to other one. Not sure where i messed up in the code..    ps: thanks for the reply

Comment: change your secomd `const dbname = "crud_mongodb"` to be the name of the database you want.

Comment: thanks a lot i (somehow..) managed it to work!